# How can i create following lighting effect in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, lighting-effects

How can i create similar lighting effect in Adobe Illustrator?
Marked with black border.

[image]

Another [Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg2A7.jpg).

Comment: Hi Shizoka, welcome to GD.SE, you should limit your question, in the bigger picture that you put as an example, I have counted 24 lighting effects, which one of them do you have problems to make? In the question title you talk about Adobe Illustrator and in the tags you only include Photoshop.

Comment: @Danielillo Hi,Light emitted from the block.marked with blackshape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **Gradients** or a **Gradient Mesh**....

Transparency is used in the Gradient color stop, or the Gradient Mesh anchor points.

[image]

[image]

To promote the "light" aspect a bit more, you could also add a secondary shape behind the gradient mesh with a dark gradient for a sort of shadow in the "hole".

[image]

Or a light gradient to signify a stronger light....

[image]